# jEditable validation not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jeditable, edit-in-place

I wanna use jQuery validation with jEditable. Here, I'm echoing a table from my database in a while loop something like this.

```
<table id="example" class="display"  cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
    Name
    </th>
    <th>
    Phone
    </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td class="items" userid="'.$row['id'].'" id="name">'.$row['name'].'</td>
     <td class="items required" userid="'.$row['id'].'" id="phone">'.$row['phone'].'</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the jEditable script with jQuery validation codes I'm using.

```
$("td.items").each(function(index) {    
$(this).editable("handler.php", { 

onsubmit: function(settings, td) {
    var input = $(td).find('input');
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            phone: {
                number: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            phone: {
                number: 'Only numbers are allowed',

            }

        },
    });
    return ($(this).valid());
},

submitdata : {userid: $(this).attr('retailerid')},
indicator : "<img src='images/indicator.gif'>",
tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
event     : "dblclick",
onblur    : "submit",
name : 'newvalue',
id   : 'elementid',

});
});
```

Here, jEditable is working perfectly. But validation thing is not working. Is this validation code correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Quote OP:  *"Is this validation code correct?"*

It is not.  The names of the `input` elements targeted within the plugin's parameters should only reference the `name` attribute of an `input` element within a `form`, not the `id` of a cell within a `table`.

AFAIK, the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) was designed to only target `<input>` elements contained within a `<form>`.  You have neither in your code.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: Sparky672 - Then how to do validation with this jEditable? Pls help :)

Comment: @collozziza, that's not what you originally asked... I just know that you cannot use the Validation plugin unless you have `input` elements within a `form` element.  Perhaps you need to post a new question about how to properly do Validation with jEditable.

Comment: Sparky672 - Thats what i'm asking :) How to do validation with jEditable. This is the code i have. jEditable creates an `input` element when u click or dblclick right?

Comment: @collozziza, I have already answered your original question.  So now I am saying that you should post a totally new question where people familiar with jEditable can answer it.  Just remember that we are not here to construct your whole project from scratch.